# Statistics - Probability distribution & the life expectancy of a machine part

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I've tried to solve this series of questions mulitple times, but they end up incorrect.

A) Let T​ be the amount of years a machine part works. Assume the probability distribution of T is given by:

$$f(t)=\dfrac{t}4 \, e^{-t^2/8}$$

Find the probability that the machine part works beyond 3 years.

B) A similar machine part has already worked for 1/2 year, what is the probability that it will work for at least another 3 years?

C) Use the central limit theorem to find an approximate probability that the average life expectancy of 20 independent components will be at least 3 years.

Comment: Can you show us one of your failed attempts?

Comment: It's an online delivery through maple, and since I'm probably misunderstanding how to do it my answers aren't accepted.

A) f(3) = (3/4)*e^-((3^2)/8) = 0.2434

B) from 0->3.5 Integrate( f(t)=(t/4)e^−((t^2)/8) ) = 0.7837
Answer: 1 - 0.7837 = 0-2162

Comment: I thought you were calculating the probability of greater than 3 years. Your answer to (A) calculates the probability distribution at 3 years.

Comment: Thats right. I figured the chance of it lasting 3 years is the same as the chance of it lasting greater than 3 years, is that wrong? 
Edit: I realize there's no logic in that...

Comment: So in A) I need to calculate the area from 3 to infinity?

Comment: @Doran Yeah that would represent what you want.
Your answer to B is a bit weird too since it seems like you aren't using the given it has lasted at least 1/2 year

Comment: Alright, I'll do it again from t=0.5 to t=3.5, ignoring the first half year. Makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- If the density is $f(t)=\dfrac{t}4 \, e^{-t^2/8}$ then the cumulative distribution function is $F(t)=\Pr(T \le t)=\displaystyle \int_{\tau=0}^t f(\tau)\, d\tau=1-e^{-t^2/8}$ for $t\ge 0$
- But you are interested in $\Pr(T \gt t)=1-F(t)$. So the answer for (1) is $1-F(3)$ while the answer for (2) is $\dfrac{1-F(3.5)}{1-F(0.5)}$
- Question (3) probably needs you to calculate the mean and variance, which may involve more integration